# div at bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky-footer

How to show a `div.bottom` of some 100px height at the bottom of the page. If the content height is less than window's height, `div.bottom` will be shown at the bottom of the window. If the height of the content is greater than window's height it will be shown at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is called a sticky footer, and it can be done with just html and css. The basic idea is to use a wrapper with `heights: 100%` and a negative margin to move it above the very bottom. [Stole the code snippet from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page) and [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/):

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">content here!
         <div class="push"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">footer content</div>
</body>

* {

    margin: 0;
  }
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
  }
  .footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this?

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0;">Hi</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/ayaqo4

Comment: Does this require you absolutely position everything else? It seems like this would cover things up if you weren't careful.

Comment: nope, in this case when I scroll the page down the div.bottom is moved up.

Answer (score 1):

This is my personal favorite for sticky footers:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css,

```
div.pos_fixed_footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0%;
    right:0px;
    background:transparent url(../img/bg_header.png) repeat scroll center top;  
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
```

and then call in your script like this

```
<div id="pos_fixed_footer"><?php include "footer.html"; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a footer that is in the bottom of the window only if the content doesn't overflow the window, otherwise it has to go down on the page.

Just implement the code from here http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page